# How to specify file name and restrict column editing in editable datatable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a example shiny app here.  It displays **editable** datatable using `DT` package.

To enable downloading all data shown on multiple pages, I use `server=FALSE` together with `renderDT`.

What I want to achieve now is

1. restrict user to edit some specific columns. 
   The following code does not seem to work.

   `editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(column = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")))`
2. I want to specify a default file name when exporting to csv,  something like  `data.csv`. Is that possible?

Super appreciate it if someone can help me out on that. Thanks a lot.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(dplyr)    
    # UI
    ui = fluidPage(
        selectInput("nrows",
                    "select n entries",
                    choices = 100:150,
                    selected = 100,
                    multiple = FALSE),
        DT::dataTableOutput('tbl'),
                   checkboxGroupInput('datacols', 
                                      label='Select Columns:',
                                      choices= c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Specie'),
                                      selected = c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Specie'),
                                      inline=TRUE )

    )

    # SERVER
    server = function(input, output) {



        df = reactiveValues()
        observe ({

            df$dat = iris %>% .[1:input$nrows, ]

        })

        # render DT
        output$tbl = renderDT(server=FALSE, {
            datatable(df$dat %>% select(one_of(input$datacols)),
                      editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(column = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))),  #"cell",
                      extensions = "Buttons",
                      options = list(
                          dom = "Bfrtip", buttons = list("csv")))

        })


        observeEvent(input[["tbl_cell_edit"]], {
            cellinfo <- input[["tbl_cell_edit"]]
            df$dat  <- editData(df$dat,  input[["tbl_cell_edit"]])
        })

    }
    shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 5):

To disable some columns for editing, you have to give the column indices, not the column names. Moreover the key word is `columns`, not `column`:

```
editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(1,2)))
```

To specify the file name, do:

```
        buttons = list(
          list(extend = "csv", text = "Export to CSV", filename = "iris")
        )
```

Comment: Thanks!  However, I would like users to edit only a specific column. My data table columns are changing, depending on what column user like to show by check/uncheck boxes underneath the table.  Simple column index do not seem to work.  Is there any way to just make column 'Sepal Width' editable?

Comment: @zesla Do `dat <- df$dat %>% select(one_of(input$datacols))` and to get the indices of the columns, do `which(names(dat) != "Sepal.Width")`.